# BigQuery row insertions failed with Go library

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I'm getting this error "X row insertions failed" where X is a number of rows when I try to insert in bigquery.

I use this library "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery" in Golang

I attach the code here:

```
    u := table.Uploader()

    var inserts []*bigquery.StructSaver
    for _, insert := range value {
        aux := bigquery.StructSaver{Struct: insert, Schema: schema}
        inserts = append(inserts, &aux)
    }

    err := u.Put(ctx, inserts)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
    }
```

This doesn't happen  in every try and I don't know what can produce it.
Anyone got the same error?

Comment: The documentation states that

"Put returns a PutMultiError if one or more rows failed to be uploaded. The PutMultiError contains a RowInsertionError for each failed row."

So to get more error information, you can type cast the error to a PutMultiError (ex: `multiError := err.(PutMultiError)`), iterate over it, then iterate over the MultiErrors, and print each error. Refer to the documentation for more information: https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#PutMultiError

Comment: Thanks @1lann ! But the information I see just says "invalid".. Any ideas how I can get the more detailed reason?

Comment: @OğuzYıldız I'm facing same Invalid error, did you get the fix for it.

Answer (score 6):

Using `bigquery.PutMultiError` I get the following properties where `Message` profiles the failure reason.

- `Location`: column
- `Message`: what failed
- `Reason`: this can simply be `invalid`

Here is an example:

```
{Location: "speed"; Message: "Cannot convert value to integer (bad value):foobar"; Reason: "invalid"}
```

Here's an example using `PutMultiError` as mentioned by 1lann. Of note, `Put` can return a `*errors.errorString` or `bigquery.PutMultiError` so it's useful to check which you have.

```
err := u.Put(ctx, inserts)
if err != nil {
    if multiError, ok := err.(bigquery.PutMultiError); ok {
        for _, err1 := range multiError {
            for _, err2 := range err1.Errors {
                fmt.Println(err2)
            }
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible fix is to make sure the fields of your struct are exported (e.g. start with uppercase letters).

It's just a really bad error message, this is just one of the reasons you could be getting that error